# Extract pointer to data from GPtrArray

Tags: c, linux, glib

I'm using `GPtrArray` structure to hold pointers to chunks of dynamically allocated memory. As I need as simple as possible and correct freeing of memory I set callback `g_ptr_array_new_with_free_func ()` which will free one element of pointer array. Thus when I call `g_ptr_array_free()` for all elements of array is called callback which correctly freeing allocated memory. Here is some pseudo code which describe problem:

```
...
GPtrArray *stack = g_ptr_array_new_with_free_func(pt_free_stack_element);
if(...) {
    ...
    g_ptr_array_free(stack);
    ...
}

if(interrupt) {
    // Here I need to do something like pop() for stack
    // I want to get pointer at some allocated element, 
    // and remove it from stack, but without freeing 
    // memory of this element
}
```

The problem is that documentation says that any `g_ptr_array_remove()`, `g_ptr_array_remove_index()`, `g_ptr_array_remove_fast()`, `g_ptr_array_remove_index_fast()`  destroy element's memory by calling callback if it's set. As you see I have set callback.

Well, general how I could do that? How can I get pointer to the element like `g_ptr_array_index()` with deleting any mention of this pointer from array, but without freeing element's memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since GLib 2.58, you can use [`g_ptr_array_steal_index()`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/bc1443b2b68252f6530b06b61de4f95c112c6b20/glib/garray.c#L1304), which was added for precisely this reason.

```
p = g_ptr_array_steal_index (stack, i);
…
pt_free_stack_element (p);
```

If the array doesn’t need to stay in order, you can use `g_ptr_array_steal_index_fast()` instead, to make things a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
g_ptr_array_set_free_func(stack, null);
p = g_ptr_array_index(stack, i);
g_ptr_array_remove_index(stack, i);
g_ptr_array_set_free_func(stack, pt_free_stack_element);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessarily true that the callback function will destroy the memory. If your pointers are to GObjects, GArrays, etc and use a destroy function of a *_unref call then it will only destroy memory that has a ref count of zero. You can thus pop from your stack using a *_ref call to ensure it is not destroyed.
No need for any messy storing and overwriting of free functions, and it's a lot neater and memory safe.